# Vacuum Structure of Schwinger Model

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Quantum Electrodynamics in one-space and one-time dimensions ($QED_{1+1}$) for charged fermions is called the Schwinger model. If the charged fermion is massless, then the model is called the massless Schwinger model or, the Schwinger model in short. On the other hand, if the charged fermion has mass, then the model is called the massive Schwinger model.

It is often said that its vacuum structure is non-trivial.

My questions are:

- What is meant by the `vacuum structure'?
- Why is it non-trivial?

Answer (score 3):

The Schwinger model has instantons in it - locally extremal field configurations of the (bosonic part of the) classical action that are *not* the globally extremal solution known as the "true" vacuum. These often appear in gauge theories and are perturbatively inaccessible phenomena, since they are global, topological states characterized by the (possible) Poyntragin classes of the underlying principal bundle of the gauge theory.

These are a natural start for perturbation theory as "fake vacua", and above every instanton there is a tower of perturbative states created by the field creation/annihilation operators.

(A trivial vacuum structure means absense of instantons)

The instantons lead to the fermions acquiring a non-zero vacuum expectation value (because the full VEV has to sum over all instanton configurations), which then leads to the *bosonization* that also occurs in fermionic 2D CFTs, meaning only mesons appear in the low-energy spectrum.

Comment: Can you please suggest me a reference, where I can study this topic in details?

Comment: @Ome: That is a very good question. I have no particular reference I would recommend for the Schwinger model, but for instantons in general, the [nLab references](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/instanton) should be quite good.

Comment: If a gauge theory like Schwinger model has non-trivial vacuum, what are the consequences? Could you enlighten me?